# Get remaining time for a sleeping thread wake up in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

In C#, how can I get the remaining time for a sleeping thread wake up?

Comment: can you rephrase that question / clarify?

Comment: You could have invested some effort in describing the situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. You have to remember when you put the thread to sleep and do the calculation yourself.

Comment: And then you only know when it's eligible to wake up.